# WordPress 3.9 two menus in same position?

Tags: theme-development, menus, navigation

I have a new WordPress theme and I want to add extra menu, but as WordPress 3.9 allows only one menu to add in one position/places in theme? 
How can I add two menus in one position?

I purchased the theme and it has top navigation call 'top-navigation' I used that for my main menu. Below that I need another menu, but I can't add because only one menu can be add in one position in this theme. So I am struggling to add full width slim menu.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Add some context or examples?

Comment: I purchased the theme and it has top navigation call 'top-navigation' I used that for my main menu. Below that I need another menu, but I can't add because only one menu can be add in one position in this theme. So I am struggling to add full width slim menu.

Comment: What theme are you using? This a more theme-specific question.

Comment: this is the item i purchased http://jkreativ.jegtheme.com/villa/ you can see main menu below that try to add another menu

Comment: theme name is jkreativ

Comment: @saentys what did the theme author say when you contacted their support at jegtheme?

Comment: @Brad I am getting very some support from them. I raised this question but not reply yet since last Thursday.

Comment: @TomJNowell I am getting once 1 reply per day which is bit slow , I hope because this is happening due to time difference. I raised this question to 'jegtheme support' and still waiting from their reply since last Thursday.

Comment: @saentys Did you try my answer?

Comment: I tried that but didn't work because it could be file names, I theme has few header files, let me send structure to you.

Comment: @BradDalton this works my other project but didn't work for 'jegtheme' theme. Any reason you can think of?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing all the code applicable to nav menus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress allows the addition of extra nav menus.

Add this to your [child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) functions file:

```
   register_nav_menus( array(
    'secondary_menu' => 'My Second Menu'
) );
```

Add this to your header.php file or the file where you want to display your extra nav menu.

```
 <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
      <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

Change the menu_class in the code to match your existing themes nav menu or you may need to add  extra CSS to style it.

**Resources:**

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu